# Using Mathematica to find arc length of implicit function

Tags: calculus, mathematica

If I have an implicit function f(x) enclosing some area but is too hard to parameterize or simplify, how can I leverage Mathematica to calculate the numerical arc length of the function? Thank you.

Comment: What do you have?  Can you generate a set of ordered pairs and apply the shoelace algorithm?

Comment: For example, the [n-ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ellipse) function.

Comment: Do you mean something like: ArcLength[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, y}]]?

Comment: It works. Thanks.